# control destination of packaged folders (serverless framework)

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I have organised my `serverless.yml` to be in a different folder to my code.
The `serverless.yml` has the following attributes

```
package:
  include:
    - ../src/*    # Where my code is located
  exclude:
    - ./**
```

When this is packaged and deployed, there is still a `src` folder with all my code in it. I would rather the code be in the root of the deployment. Is there anyway to fine tune the actual destination folders with include/exclude or are there any other attributes I can use to achieve what I want?

This is just a simple example for the moment, the real life deployment might grow to be more complicated.

Comment: Maybe you just need to change `function.handler` path?

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I did `handler: src/lambda_handler.myhander` however the modules (python3)  inside the source folder could not be found. I hack fixed that with `sys.path.append("/var/task/src")` at the top of the lambda handler. I have this work around for the moment, but would still like to know if there is a way to have better control over the actual destination folder of the `include`, as I might want to use a more complex solution in the future